# Why isn't this JavaScript syntax supported in Google Chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, arrow-functions

I initiated a JavaScript/jQuery click listener like this:

```
$("#test").on("click", () => {
   console.log("test");
});
```

This piece of code works perfectly fine in Firefox but in Chrome this seems to give me a Syntax error.
Why is this, since this looks like 'ok' syntax to me.

You can test this quickly in the console by doing

```
 var a = () => {return 0;}
 a();
```

In Firefox 27.0.1 this returns 0
In Chrome it returns `SyntaxError: Unexpected token )`

Comment: What background you have so that lambda expressions are "ok syntax to you"? Everyone is excited to have it finally in the draft but it takes time until the draft is accepted and the feature is implemented. There were never lambdas in javascript before.

Comment: @WiktorZychla - Perhaps he got it [from CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/#fat-arrow)? Just a guess though.

Comment: @JamesAllardice: or TypeScript, that's why I am curious.

Comment: @WiktorZychla no, lambdas have been there for ages - this is just a new syntax ;-) 
eg:var a = function(){return 0;}; ... also $("#test").on("click", function(){
   console.log("test");
});

Comment: @imma: most people asked what is the difference will not recognize anonymous functions as "lambdas" just because "lambda" commonly refers to the new "arrow syntax". Technically then you wre right but the question is specifically about the new syntax.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The **fat arrow** is [a feature of ES6](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2013/09/10/understanding-ecmascript-6-arrow-functions/) (now officially called ECMAScript 2015). It's been introduced in Firefox but not yet in other browsers (and especially [not completely in V8](https://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=2700) which would be interesting for nodejs/iojs development).

As it's mostly sugar, you'd better wait before using it.

If you *need* the scope binding (`this` is the same in the function call and in the scope in which the function was defined, we speak of "lexical this"), then instead of

```
$("#test").on("click", () => {
   some code
});
```

you can simply do

```
$("#test").on("click", (function() {
   some code
}).bind(this));
```

If you don't (as in your example), then simply do

```
$("#test").on("click", function() {
   console.log("test");
});
```

Comment: In the second sample you don't need the parenthesis around the function. `$("#test").on("click", function() {
   some code
}.bind(this));` Is valid

Comment: @plus- right, but it's only because it's in a place where an expression is expected (you couldn't have `function() { some code }.bind(this)` outside, or in the console). Just like with semicolon, I prefer to  keep one always working syntax. It's also easier to read in my opinion.

Comment: Functions defined with arrow syntax are bound to window by default. Their equivalent would be `function() { some code }.bind(Window)`

Comment: @MarcoLuglio You got it wrong. Please have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Lexical_this

Comment: so please clarify how is `this` getting defined in fat arrow function, im having javascript crisis

Comment: Awesome !!. I tried it in Chrome (Version 48.0.2564.97 (64-bit)
) recently and found it working. Have a look.

Comment: Yes it's working in all major browsers now (this answer is one year old).