# JavaScript google maps event handler gives error - 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token >' using fat arrow function

Tags: javascript, google-maps, scope

http://robcee.net/2013/fat-arrow-functions-in-javascript/ - checked my syntax here

I am trying to use it in my code but it gives this error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token >
```

at this line

```
google.maps.event.addListener(this.map, "rightclick", (event) => {
```

in this code

```
google.maps.event.addListener(this.map, "rightclick", (event) => {
     this.showContextMenu(event);
});
```

If i replace the fat arrow function by this

```
var self = this;
google.maps.event.addListener(this.map, "rightclick", self.showContextMenu);
```

It works fine. but, the I do not have access to the variables that i want to have. hence, to fix the scoping issue I used fat arrow function. Does anyone know why it aint working in my code. To me the syntax looks right for fat arrow function

Comment: "(event) => {" isn't valid syntax.  The last argument of the addListener function needs to be a function "pointer" or something that returns a function "pointer".

Comment: Do you know what is the right syntax then to be able to use fat arrow function?

Comment: I think "fat arrow" functions work only in [FireFox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/arrow_functions) at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Why isn't this JavaScript syntax supported in Google Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21856772/why-isnt-this-javascript-syntax-supported-in-google-chrome)

Fat arrow function is not implemented in Chrome yet.

However, Firefox does support it. - see screenshot below

[image]