# SetTimeout never calls function

Tags: javascript

I created a loop to simulate a long running operation. Here it is:

```
var b1, b2;
b1 = true;
b2 = false;
while (b1) {
    if (!b2) {
        setTimeout(function() => {
            b1 = false;
        }, 1000);
       b2 = true;
     }
}
```

Any ideas on why `b1 = true;` never happens?

Comment: you need to "yield".

Comment: `=>` is not an operator in Javascript?

Comment: Assuming your environment will support ES6, your script will still produce a never ending loop, as the callback of the timeout will not be called before the `while` loop finished.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`setTimeout` only schedules a function to be executed after `n` seconds. The function is put on the thread execution stack in the same manner as any other after that period elapses.

In this case the timeout function will **not interrupt** the execution of your `while` loop. It will execute after main thread execution is finished.... so never.

You can take a look at the HTML5 draft spec for timers [here](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/webappapis.html#timers).

Answer (score 0):

your syntax for setTimeout is incorrect

```
var b1, b2;
b1 = true;
b2 = false;
while (b1) {
    if (!b2) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            b1 = false;
        }, 1000);
       b2 = true;
     }
}
```

Comment: from the console: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )

Comment: It is not supported in Chrome. See [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21856772/why-isnt-this-javascript-syntax-supported-in-google-chrome)