# Expected () to start arrow function, but got ';' instead of '=>'

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have block of jquery which I am struggling with. The aim is to call a partial method, which it does on the first button click, but any subsequent clicks causes the error

> Expected () to start arrow function, but got ';' instead of '=>'

I have tried replacing semi colons, swapping function() for () => and various other combinations, but I really have no idea where i am meant to exchange the ; for a => (I assume that is what the error is telling me to do?)

```
$().ready(function () {
    $(".page-number").on("click", function () {
        var selectedPage = parseInt($(this).html());
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("_PartialViewBeingCalled", "Pv")',
            data: { 'page': selectedPage },
            success: function (data) {
                $("#pvId").html(data)
            }
        })
    })
})
```

following reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21856772/why-isnt-this-javascript-syntax-supported-in-google-chrome) I also tried to add the below to the code block to the end

```
.bind(this)
```

What does this error mean and how do I resolve it? (and why does it work the first time but not on subsequent calls?)

EDIT:

I added a `fail: function(data) { console.log(data) }` to my ajax request and the entire contents of my entire page, partialview and page calling the partialview was return twice shown below (Please note the script is also returned twice - I assume it makes no difference where I hold the script for testing?):

```
<div id="properties">
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Visible</th>
                <th>Address</th>
                <th>Contact</th>
                <th>Telephone</th>
                <th>Email ID.</th>
                <th>Viewings</th>
                <th>Book Viewing</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="7">
                    <div id="dataTables-example_filter" class="dataTables_filter">
                        <input type="search" class="form-control input-sm" aria-controls="dataTables-example" placeholder="Search:">
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>
                <tr class='clickable-row' data-href='<a href="/Property/Index/5">Property</a>'>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                    <td>test</td>
                    <td>WV60NH</td>
                    <td>test</td>
                    <td>test</td>
                    <td>5</td>
                    <td><a href="&lt;a href=&quot;/Property/Index/5&quot;&gt;Property&lt;/a&gt;" class="btn btn-default fa fa-book"> Book</a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class='clickable-row' data-href='<a href="/Property/Index/5">Property</a>'>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                    <td>test</td>
                    <td>WV60NH</td>
                    <td>test</td>
                    <td>test</td>
                    <td>5</td>
                    <td><a href="&lt;a href=&quot;/Property/Index/5&quot;&gt;Property&lt;/a&gt;" class="btn btn-default fa fa-book"> Book</a></td>
                </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="dataTables_length" id="dataTables-example_length">
            <label>
                <select name="dataTables-example_length" aria-controls="dataTables-example" class="form-control input-sm">
                    <option value="10">10</option>
                    <option value="25">25</option>
                    <option value="50">50</option>
                    <option value="100">100</option>
                </select> records per page
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="dataTables_paginate paging_simple_numbers" id="dataTables-example_paginate">
            <ul class="pagination pull-right">
                    <li class="paginate_button" aria-controls="dataTables-example" tabindex="0">
                        <a href="javascript:void();" class="page-number">1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="paginate_button" aria-controls="dataTables-example" tabindex="0">
                        <a href="javascript:void();" class="page-number">2</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="paginate_button" aria-controls="dataTables-example" tabindex="0">
                        <a href="javascript:void();" class="page-number">3</a>
                    </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<script>


$(function () {
    $(".page-number").on("click", function () {
        var selectedPage = parseInt($(this).html());



        $.ajax({
            url: '/Property/_PropertyTable',
            data: { 'page': selectedPage },
            fail: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                $("#properties").html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>

Index:436 
<div id="properties">
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Visible</th>
                <th>Address</th>
                <th>Contact</th>
                <th>Telephone</th>
                <th>Email ID.</th>
                <th>Viewings</th>
                <th>Book Viewing</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="7">
                    <div id="dataTables-example_filter" class="dataTables_filter">
                        <input type="search" class="form-control input-sm" aria-controls="dataTables-example" placeholder="Search:">
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>
                <tr class='clickable-row' data-href='<a href="/Property/Index/5">Property</a>'>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                    <td>test</td>
                    <td>WV60NH</td>
                    <td>test</td>
                    <td>test</td>
                    <td>5</td>
                    <td><a href="&lt;a href=&quot;/Property/Index/5&quot;&gt;Property&lt;/a&gt;" class="btn btn-default fa fa-book"> Book</a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class='clickable-row' data-href='<a href="/Property/Index/5">Property</a>'>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                    <td>test</td>
                    <td>WV60NH</td>
                    <td>test</td>
                    <td>test</td>
                    <td>5</td>
                    <td><a href="&lt;a href=&quot;/Property/Index/5&quot;&gt;Property&lt;/a&gt;" class="btn btn-default fa fa-book"> Book</a></td>
                </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="dataTables_length" id="dataTables-example_length">
            <label>
                <select name="dataTables-example_length" aria-controls="dataTables-example" class="form-control input-sm">
                    <option value="10">10</option>
                    <option value="25">25</option>
                    <option value="50">50</option>
                    <option value="100">100</option>
                </select> records per page
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="dataTables_paginate paging_simple_numbers" id="dataTables-example_paginate">
            <ul class="pagination pull-right">
                    <li class="paginate_button" aria-controls="dataTables-example" tabindex="0">
                        <a href="javascript:void();" class="page-number">1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="paginate_button" aria-controls="dataTables-example" tabindex="0">
                        <a href="javascript:void();" class="page-number">2</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="paginate_button" aria-controls="dataTables-example" tabindex="0">
                        <a href="javascript:void();" class="page-number">3</a>
                    </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<script>


$(function () {
    $(".page-number").on("click", function () {
        var selectedPage = parseInt($(this).html());



        $.ajax({
            url: '/Property/_PropertyTable',
            data: { 'page': selectedPage },
            fail: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                $("#properties").html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: That error looks like a syntax error. Your code would not run if it had a syntax error, yet you're claiming it runs correctly the first time. Are you certain that this is the problem code?

Answer (score 3):

I found the problem. It's `javascript:void();`. You should remove it. Hope it help.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following

```
$(function () {
    $(".page-number").on("click", function () {
        var selectedPage = parseInt($(this).html());
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("_PartialViewBeingCalled", "Pv")',
            data: { 'page': selectedPage },
            success: function (data) {
                $("#pvId").html(data)
            }
        })
    })
})
```

Hope, thus it would work!

Comment: Thankyou but I still get the same error. But isnt `$().ready(function () {` and `$(function () {` the same thing?

Comment: I dont think, both are same. `$().ready(function () {` should be `$(document).ready(function () {` . Can you try by creating the URL variable `url: '@Url.Action("_PartialViewBeingCalled", "Pv")',` before of the script tag

Comment: Creating the `var par = "Pv/_PartialViewBeingCalled"` before the script causes GET[url] 404 (Not Found). But creating `var par = ''@Url.Action("_PartialViewBeingCalled", "Pv")''` returns the same error

Comment: Can you take `'@Url.Action("_PartialViewBeingCalled", "Pv")'` in one simple variable and try assigning it to the JS variable.

Comment: Sorry I thought that is what i did when I did `var par = '@Url.Action("_PartialViewBeingCalled", "Pv")'`

Comment: you coding on .NET platform, right? So, create a .NET variable I meant to say with the former one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91669/discussion-between-tony09uk-and-abhijeet-k).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I would have ever received an answer, the problem wasn't my jquery, but it was that I was trying to update a partial view and using the html helper

`@{Html.RenderAction("_PartialView", "Controller");}`

changing this to

`@{Html.RenderPartial("_PartialView");}`

Resolved the issue. I also moved my script into a separate file